# How exactly does tuple slicing work in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, slice

For list slicing I could imagine (although I could be totally off...) the code being something along the lines of instantiating a list of size *range_end - range_start* and inputting values from the original list into the newly created array.

How exactly does tuple slicing work? It's not like we could potentially instantiate a tuple of size *range_end - range_start* and update the values since tuples are immutable.

I've tried a couple of tests and it seems tuple slicing and list slicing perform similarly on average:

```
import time

_max = 10000000
_list = range(_max)
_tuple = tuple(_list)

mid = _max // 2
i = 10000
while i <= _max:
    print 'for', i,  ' elements :'
    s = mid - half
    e = mid + half - 1
    # list slice
    start = time.clock()
    lSlice = _list[s:e]
    end = time.clock()
    print 'list slice took:',  end - start
    # tuple slice
    start = time.clock()
    tSlice = _tuple[s:e]
    end = time.clock()
    print 'tuple slice took:', end - start
    i *= 10
```

Which yielded:

```
for 10000  elements :
list slice took: 6.78296778938e-05
tuple slice took: 2.94523601381e-05
for 100000  elements :
list slice took: 0.000377971955106
tuple slice took: 0.000270872463694
for 1000000  elements :
list slice took: 0.00472353381912
tuple slice took: 0.00548037022509
for 10000000  elements :
list slice took: 0.0499159492116
tuple slice took: 0.0504157468382
```

Could anyone give me some insight into how the tuple slicing routine works?

edit: I noticed my setup for start and end points of slices were ridiculous so I updated the code snippet.

Comment: Being "immutable" just means that the objects *doesn't expose any methods* which can mutate it, but you can probably hack some way to mutate it, and the implementation certainly can mutate the underlying primitive array.

Comment: Since the C code can be sure that the Python-end user cannot mutate the tuple, and the tuple has a fixed size, you can make certain guarantees about the size of the tuple which make everything simpler.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I'm guessing an underlying primitive array is generated upon the slicing call, which is then updated and reflected in the sliced tuple..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's not like we could potentially instantiate a tuple of size range_end - range_start and update the values since tuples are immutable.

You can't at Python level, but it's entirely possible in the underlying C implementation, and [that's how it's done](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/tupleobject.c#L717). That's how *any* tuple gets its values filled in, whether through slicing, the `tuple` constructor, `(a, b, c)` syntax, or anything else.

```
else if (PySlice_Check(item)) {
    ...
        result = PyTuple_New(slicelength);
        if (!result) return NULL;

        src = self->ob_item;
        dest = ((PyTupleObject *)result)->ob_item;
        for (cur = start, i = 0; i < slicelength;
             cur += step, i++) {
            it = src[cur];
            Py_INCREF(it);
            dest[i] = it;
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even know this repository existed until now. I'll be sure to refer to this repo whenever I have questions on how something in python is implemented. Thanks a a lot!